# BigQuery list all datasets within project

Tags: c#, list, enums, google-bigquery

I'm currently trying to construct a query within C# by dynamically querying the tables I need from BigQuery. I found out about a way you can query the project and get all datasets within it but am having a rough time getting it working.

```
static public List<BigQueryDataset> ListDatasets(BigQueryClient client)
{
    var datasets = client.ListDatasets().ToList();
    return datasets;
}

object datasets = ListDatasets(client);
```

`datasets` contains a list/enum of `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryDataset`. I do not know how to get the actual name of the dataset out of this. I'm extremely new to C# and even newer to BigQuery so any help at all would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
[..]
List<BigQueryDataset> datasets = client.ListDatasets().Take(20).ToList();
foreach (BigQueryDataset dataset in datasets){
   Console.WriteLine(dataset.FullyQualifiedId);
}
[..]
```

See more snippets [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.Snippets).