# Export Google BigQuery datasets in a single project as list in bq command-line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, google-bigquery, bq

I've looked at [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bq) resource, but it's not quite what I need. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598458/bigquery-list-all-datasets-within-project) is what I want to accomplish, but I want to run it in the BQ terminal.

For instance, in the past I've exported table information as a .json in bq command-line as so:

> bq show --schema --format=prettyjson Dataset.TableView > /home/directory/Dataset.TableView.json

This gives a prettyjson of Table information of a specified dataset in a set project. I would like to just have a .csv (or any type of list) of **all** dataset names in the project. But I can't figure out how to change that command-line appropriately to output what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to further contribute to the community, as an alternative to @DanielZagales answer, using the `bq` command line. According to the documentation, you can use the `bq ls` to list all [the datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets#listing_datasets_in_a_project) in a project. Such as follows,

`bq ls -a --format=pretty --project_id your-project-id`

The flag `-a` is short for `--all`, which guarantees that all the datasets will be included in the list. The flag `--format=pretty` will output the list as a table format, you can use other formatting such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_global_flags). Furthermore, you can also filter the datasets which match an expression with `--filter labels.key:value` or set the maximum number of results with `--max_results` or `-n`.

Note: you can also list all the tables within a dataset, such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#listing_tables).

Comment: @speakwiththepen, if you find this information useful, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query the information schema to get the results you want.
example:

```
select * from `project_id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`;
```

You can then add that to the bq command like:

```
bq query --format=csv 'select * from `project_id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`;'
```

Comment: Ah, my inexperience with BQ shows. Didn't even think about running it in the console. It works, thanks.

Comment: You can still run it in the command line with bq query